# Docker Basic connection to local dynamodb configuration

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-dynamodb

I am using a symfony app and connecting to a local dynamodb instance in a docker container.

I keep getting `AWS HTTP error: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to db port 8889: Connection refused` error.

My docker-compose file is simply:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    depends_on:
        - db
    build: .
    ports:
        - "8000:8000"
  db:
    image: "amazon/dynamodb-local"
    ports:
        - "8889:8889"
```

Honestly, I always get confused by the port mapping, but I don't think that should matter here. I'm trying to connect to `http://db:8889`. To make things simpler, I executed the following inside my `web` container:

```
# curl http://db:8889
curl: (7) Failed to connect to db port 8889: Connection refused
```

I'm kinda stumped, and I think this is such a simple thing most of the docs skim right over it. (or maybe I do)

Comment: Can you try omitting the `http://` part in the connection url?

Answer (score 1):

[The image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local/) suggests the DynamoDB server runs on port 8000, so you should access it as `http://db:8000`.  You don't have to publish it on port 8000 or on any port at all, but you need to use the container-side port number to reach it from other containers.